# Spring 'request' scope thowring exception while using from ExecutorService

Tags: spring, multithreading, executorservice

I have a controller and 3 service beans. My goal is to fire 3 concurrent `REST` Services from `ExecutorService` with request scope.

I am getting below exception while its trying to initialize bean at request scope for 3 times for each `@autowired` service bean.

Can some one please help me find out root cause and resolve the issue.

```
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.RestService1: Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private RestService1 restService1;
    @Autowired
    private RestService2 restService2;
    @Autowired
    private RestService3 restService3;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testConcurency",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody testConcurency(@Valid @RequestBody TestRequest req, BindingResult errors) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService executor = null;
        Collection<Callable<TestResponse>> tasks = new ArrayList();
        tasks.add(restService1);
        tasks.add(restService2);
        tasks.add(restService3);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tasks.size());
        List<Future<KycResponse>> list = executor.invokeAll(tasks,30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}


@Service
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RestService1 implements IThreadService, Callable<KycResponse>{
    @Override
    public TestResponse call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello from"+this);
        // REST service will be called from here.
    }
}
```

Web.xml I have added a listener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ExecutorService, the Runnables will be executed in a different thread than the web request, so the request scope is not accessible in that other thread (since you have no running request there). A solution would be to change the scope of that service beans to application scope (of course make sure first, that they programmed to handle that, i.e. no state etc.).

Comment: Hello @dunny, Understood your point. Changing this would lead to many file edits now. I have tried two options, 1) To make it Scope("prototype"). But still i am getting same object reference for each service bean. At least if Spring creates fresh bean each time would solve my problem. 2) Created local variables for each service bean and then its throwing NullPointerException from service bean Inject variables.